# Pitfalls associated with moving a physical Cassandra cluster to a cloud based cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cloud, datastax-enterprise

We're discussing transitioning our physical infrastructure to a cloud based solution, for a number of reasons, but a major one is so that we can scale out much more easily, along with all of the other "not having to host/maintain physical hardware" benefits you get with a cloud solution.

That said, with Cassandra being a shared nothing architecture, what kind of performance hits will we most likely experience?  For starters we'd be sharing physical resources most likely storage, etc so how big an impact could this potentially be?

I know companies like NetFlix have large cloud based cassandra clusters, but I'm assuming with their budget they can afford to have their stuff sitting on its own hardware and not sharing anything with any other companies...we obviously don't have that kind of budget.

Just trying to get an idea of any major pitfalls to look for now, especially from anybody who has successfully done a migration like this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at two things (For what I know of):

**Encryption**

This needs to be secure. Your data in the Cassandra system is probably not all encrypted and either way it would not be secure to not encrypt data traveling between nodes. You may be able to find a cloud provider that can give you a way to skip that step. If you cannot do so, there is a huge impact on speed. The encryption is not cheap, CPU wise.

**Bandwidth**

You may want to measure the amount of traffic you have between your existing nodes. Having them in a cloud is all good, as long as your computers are closed and have a local network connection.

If you use a cloud system where all the traffic travels through the Internet port instead of a local port, that's going to cost you a HUGE amount in bandwidth. From what I've seen with Cassandra, when a node goes down, the amount of traffic increases dramatically until that node comes back. that problem may be fixed in newer versions of Cassandra, I've not tested that again lately...